# How to notify an app that credentials were successful in Django/Tastypie/REST

Tags: python, django, tastypie, restful-authentication

I kind of understand how login works with TastyPie and Django but there's one thing that's bothering me. 
Once something like

```
 {"username": username,"password":password} or "apikey":apikey
```

is sent through the api by HttpRequest and the necessary authentication is done, how would the mobile app know that it was successful?
What code would I use to tell the native app that authentication was successful and thus it can proceed.

I found this code here on SO and understand part of it but in the case of a non browser app, how will it know?

class UserResource(ModelResource):

```
class Meta:
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'user'
    allowed_methods = ['post']


def prepend_urls(self):
    return [
        url(r"^user/login/$", self.wrap_view('login'), name="api_login"),
        url(r"^user/logout/$", self.wrap_view('logout'), name='api_logout'),
    ]

def login(self, request, **kwargs):
    self.method_check(request, allowed=['post'])

    data = self.deserialize(request, request.raw_post_data, format=request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json'))

    username = data.get('username', '')
    password = data.get('password', '')

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return self.create_response(request, {
                'success': True
            })
        else:
            return self.create_response(request, {
                'success': False,
                'reason': 'disabled',
            }, HttpForbidden )
    else:
        return self.create_response(request, {
            'success': False,
            'reason': 'incorrect',
            }, HttpUnauthorized )

def logout(self, request, **kwargs):
    self.method_check(request, allowed=['post'])
    if request.user and request.user.is_authenticated():
        logout(request)
        return self.create_response(request, { 'success': True })
    else:
        return self.create_response(request, { 'success': False }, HttpUnauthorized)
```

EDIT:

Asked differently...
How can I notify this independent python script:

```
url="http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/api/article/"

data={
    'title':'Tastypie Madness',
    'body':'First Restful client. Enjoy',
    'pub_date':str(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')),
    }
files=  {'thumbnail': open('car.jpg', 'rb')}

req = requests.post(url, data=data, files=files)
```

that the object that was created and SAVED successfully through this api:

class ArticleResource(ModelResource):

```
class Meta:
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'article'
    filtering = {'title': ALL}
    authorization=Authorization()

def deserialize(self, request, data, format=None):

        if not format:
             format = request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json')
        if format =='application/x-www-form-urlencoded':
            data = request.POST.copy()
            photo = Article()
            photo.title = request.POST.get('title')
            photo.body=request.POST.get('body')
            photo.pub_date = request.POST.get('pub_date')
            photo.save()
            return data
        if format.startswith('multipart'):
            data = request.POST.copy()
            photo = Article()
            photo.thumbnail = request.FILES['thumbnail']
            photo.title = request.POST.get('title')
            photo.body=request.POST.get('body')
            photo.pub_date = request.POST.get('pub_date')
            photo.save()
            # ... etc 
            return data
        return super(ArticleResource, self).deserialize(request, data, format)

    # overriding the save method to prevent the object getting saved twice 
def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
         pass
```

and printing "Successfully Posted" on the screen.

Comment: How do you get the server's answer in your client?

Comment: @spectras yes, that's what I'm asking. Do I have to manually request it?

Comment: Well, your client app will submit the request, like you wrote. The server will perform something, then send back an answer, that your client app will parse. The sample code does that already, the only question is: what kind of client app do you have? browser-based with jquery? some phone framework? You need to know how to get the answer using your specific toolsuite. It is a client issue, not a server issue. Server is already sending the answer.

Comment: @spectras Oh I think I'm starting to understand. Thanks for answering, For simplicity, lets say I write a client side standalone python script whose sole purpose was to send a username/password combination and get a success/fail response which it prints to screen. So not browser based. How would I do that?

Comment: import requests,json;
print(requests.post(url, data=json.dumps({"username": username,"password":password})).text)

Comment: @spectras I've edited the question to give an idea of what I'm looking for

Comment: If it returns 200 the login was successful, can't you use that?

Answer (score 0):

specifically in your code:

```
req = requests.post(url, data=data, files=files)
```

if req.status_code == 200, then you've authenticated properly. looks like you're using the requests library, here's a little more info about what response content looks like and how to access it:

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content